# Hibernate Envers: Better way to add multiple Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I want to add projections on selected fields as I can not pass whole result list. 
I am doing this to achieve the same.

```
List resultList = reader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(MyAsset.class, false, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(assetId))
            .add(AuditEntity.property("quantity").hasChanged())
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc())
            .addProjection(AuditEntity.property("updatedAt", "updatedAt"))
            .addProjection(AuditEntity.property("updatedBy", "updatedBy"))
            .addProjection(AuditEntity.property("quantity", "quantity"))
            .getResultList();
```

Is there any better way to do the same? Something like Custom Projections.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative other than what you've shown for adding projections.

If you have an idea on how to improve this, you're welcomed to open a RFE [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net) and supply your ideas on how you'd like to see it enhanced.  If you have the time, you're also welcomed to submit a workable solution via  PR and we can review it and offer some input.